# Can a tree touching a 220v cable act as ground?

Tags: electricity

I found a  tree which is touching the 220 volts  electricity wire. Can that tree act as a ground and can drain electricity? Is it hazardous and should be cut?

[image]

Comment: trees can be used as monopole antennas...

Comment: This is not a physics question but, as far as the power company is concerned, 220V is _low voltage_.  They don't like to see trees touching overhead power lines, but trimming trees that touch low-voltage lines probably is a low priority for them.

Comment: @jameslarge why isn't it physics?

Comment: @FGSUZ because it isn't a question about the laws of the universe or, about how to solve equations that describe the laws of the universe.  Questions about is-this-situation-in-my-neighborhood-a-public-safety-hazard are pretty far off topic even if there is a physical explanation of _why_ it is a public safety hazard.

Comment: Well, that's your opinion, but I do not share. The question is actually "is a tree a good conductor of electricity, and why?". For me it's interesting from the physical point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 220V wire has no insulation, a tree touching it could definitely cause a current flowing to ground. Especially when it is wet. Also, the tree movements could lead to a break of the wire. Thus the branches should be cut!